# Maven is not combining the R.java files the same way that Eclipse does

Tags: android, maven, r.java-file

I have a file in my res/raw folder that I am able to view properly when I compile with Eclipse.  When the same project is compiled with Maven through Continuous Integration the file is not coming through as I expect.

In Eclipse I have an API project and a UI project.  The API project needs to be built first since the UI project calls into the API.  The API project was brought into the UI project as a Link Source and so the source is included nicely within Eclipse.

For my CI with Maven, I have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myapp.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>API</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I run the app that was Maven built the resource id that I have referenced in the API is duplicated in the UI as a different resource id and so my res/raw file in the API is not found.

What am I missing in order to have Maven fold the R.java files together the way that Eclipse has done?

Comment: Do you use android library project?

Comment: I don't believe so.  What would be the best way to determine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two separated android projects, take a look at maven-android-plugin.
[Here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib) is short description how to use android library projects and [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=96) more details and troubleshooting.

Comment: I have found that I my API project is an android library. I have had some success with the ApkLib that you referenced. I have now encountered a problem with an external library, ksoap2, that is not being included properly.  I have not changed how that is in my pom, but maybe I need to?

Comment: Make sure that your dependencies are properly configured in pom. If not, project won't build or you'll get ClassNotFoundExceptions in runtime.

Comment: That is exactly where I am at. I have setup a parent pom with this dependency '        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.ksoap2-android</groupId>
          <artifactId>ksoap2-android</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
'

Comment: My project now is building an app that runs as I expect it to run. I removed the <scope>provided</scope> tag from the dependency.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it with Android, but you could try the [Eclipse plugin for Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/). From the command line, run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This will generate your .project and .classpath for you based on your pom file. Again, I haven't tried it with Android, but it does a good job with other kinds of projects (wars, jars).

Comment: I need to go the other way.  My Eclipse project works the way I want.  I need the pom to behave the way that Eclipse is behaving.